# Can we create custom fields in Azure Active Directory - B2B?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

I've an Azure Active Directory for B2B client.

AAD provides all the necessary fields like name, email, custom email, etc.

I need to store some more information in it.

I'm using a VOIP provider and it has a unique data for each User, I need to store some of that data in AAD itself.

I've seen B2C allows us to create the custom fields.

My question is can we create the custom fields in AAD-B2B, if yes then how to create it?

I did not found any well documented steps for that

Comment: You can add app-specific extensions with a couple methods described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview

Comment: Will these be reflected on the GUI i.e. Azure portal?

Comment: No, they are only accessible via the API.